# Data on Google Analytics reports for "pages" doesn't match the report for "page titles"

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I am curious as to what would cause the data for Pages to report differently than Page Titles, in theory, shouldn't they be the same?

For instance, using the month of October, under "Pages" and looking at the top 10 pages and then going to "Page Titles" not only does the order of the top 10 change, so do the number of pageviews for a corresponding page url.

Example

Under "Page" for `example.com/pet/dogs/stay`  the views are 20
Under "Page Title" for `example.com/pet/dogs/stay` the views are 50

Why? What causes the change? Is this normal? If not, how to resolve?

Comment: Could there be multiple pages with the same title (or alternate URLs for a page)?

Comment: We checked and there isn't which is creating more to this mystery.

Comment: If you have query parameters that aren't filtered out the URLs will be counted separately under Page but together under Page Title. Have you ruled out that kind of "alternate URL"?

Comment: No, that wasn't taken into consideration. Thank you for this and hopefully this helps bring it closer to apple:apple vs current state